#  Event of FiddlerApp descirbing moment when page is completely loaded

Tags: c#, fiddler

What event of FiddlerApplication specifies moment when page is fully loaded into web browser? Event AfterSessionComplete is fired before all page items are loaded...
I am using exteral dll (fiddlercore).

```
  Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += delegate(Fiddler.Session session) 
  {
       Console.WriteLine("End time:\t" + session.fullUrl + ", " + session.Timers.ClientDoneResponse.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));                }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This question was answered an hour before you posted here in the forum where you originally asked it.*

A web proxy (e.g. Fiddler) cannot possibly know when a web browser is 
finished loading a page. Even if you were running code in the web 
browser itself, it's a non-trivial exercise.

About the closest you could come is to use the proxy to inject 
JavaScript which then emits out the timing information to the network 
for the proxy to catch, but even doing this from JavaScript isn't 
necessarily precise.